# Mejorar rendimiento en comparacion de campos

Tags: python, python-3.x

Estoy realizando un proceso que debe comparar 3 campos en un tabla en busca de duplicados.

Lo que se hizo fue crear otra tabla con los mismos registro y tomar un registro de la TABLA 1 y compararlo con todos los registros de la TABLA B, esta técnica tarda demasiado ya que tenemos 100 mil registros que se deben de comparar.

Se planteo de la siguiente manera suprimiendo la comparacion del mismo campo en la segunda consulta.

```
def xNumero(campoA,campo1,CampoB,campo2,CampoC,Campo3):

    resultado1= fuzz.token_sort_ratio(CampoA, Campo1)

    resultado2= fuzz.token_sort_ratio(CampoB, Campo2)

    resultado3= fuzz.token_sort_ratio(CampoC, Campo3)

    score = (resultado1+resultado2+resultado3) / 3

    return(score)


sqlOrigen = ("Select campoA,campoB,campoC from TABLA A")

cursor.execute(sqlOrigen)

for d in cursor:

    campoA= d[0]
    campoB= d[1]
    campoC= d[2]

    sqlComparacion = ("Select campo1,campo2,campo3 from TABLA B
                       where campo1 <> %s") % \
                       (campoA)

    cursorConsulta.execute(sqlComparacion)

     for r in  cursorConsulta:

        campo1= d[0]
        campo2= d[1]
        campo3= d[2]
```

> Se llama a una funcion que con la libreria fuzzywuzzy realiza la
>   comparacion de los campos y devuelve el porcentaje de comparacion.

```
result = xNumero(campoA,campo1,campoB,campo2,campoC,campo3)
```

Esta funcion devuelve un porcentaje del total del promedio de las comparaciones de los 3 campos que luego se determina si segun el valor devuelto se toma para considerar como duplicado o no y se guarda en una tabla aparte.

Este proceso resulta muy lento, como se podria mejorar?, creo que un buen metodo seria comparar sobre una unica tabla pero solo es una idea.

Comment: No sé si entiendo bien el problema, ni si lo que voy a proponer será apropiado, pero se me ocurre leer la tabla completa en memoria y realizar un `sort()` sobre la misma, con una función de comparación propia (key) que tome los tres campos y la función fuzzy para crear un resultado único en base al cual ordenar. Una vez ordenada, los elementos contiguos en esa tabla serían los más parecidos entre sí.

Comment: ¿Que motor de base de datos estas usando? ¿No tendrá ya alguna funcionalidad de comparación difusa? Es difícil, casi diría imposible responder esta pregunta sin conocer que es lo que está haciendo  `xNumero` y sin tener una idea de como son los datos.

Comment: Sql 2017, se añadio la funcion. Los datos son string.

Comment: puedes usar un not in `"Select campo1,campo2,campo3 from TABLA B
                       where campo1 not in(%s, %s,%s") % \
                       (campoA,campoB,campoC)`

Comment: Pero siempre tendria 2 consultas en dos tablas